# unordered_map is unable to retrieve value for a key specified as a variable in argument

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I need to extract specific values from the unordered_map. However, unordered_map is unable to lookup with a variable inside its box brackets.

In the below code `cout << m[code[i]] << " ";` is throwing an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string code;
    cout << "Enter code: ";
    getline(cin, code);

    unordered_map<string, string> m = {
        {"A","Jan"},{"B","Feb"},{"C","Mar"},{"D","Apr"},
        {"E","May"},{"F","Jun"},{"G","Jul"},{"H","Aug"},
        {"I","Sep"},{"J","Oct"},{"K","Nov"},{"L","Dec"}
    };

    for(int i=0 ; i<code.length() ; i++) {
        cout << m[code[i]] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Error msg:**

> main.cpp:18:18: No viable overloaded operator[] for type
>   'unordered_map' (aka 'unordered_map, allocator >, basic_string, allocator > >')

Comment: Do not tell anybody what error you are getting, that would be more interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `code` with type `string`, `code[i]` returns a `char` (but not a `string`); which doesn't match the key type of the map.

You can change the type of map to `unordered_map<char, string>`, e.g.

```
unordered_map<string, string> m = {
    {'A',"Jan"},{'B',"Feb"},{'C',"Mar"},{'D',"Apr"},
    {'E',"May"},{'F',"Jun"},{'G',"Jul"},{'H',"Aug"},
    {'I',"Sep"},{'J',"Oct"},{'K',"Nov"},{'L',"Dec"}
};
```

If you want to work with `unordered_map<string, string>`, you have to pass a `string` to `unordered_map::operator[]`. e.g.

```
cout << m[string(1, code[i])] << " ";
```

Comment: Somebody need to make a VS plugin that would redirect compiler error directly to SO, these people do not bother to read and comprehend them anyway. They do not even bother to paste error messages to their questions. Why bother, if somebody like @songyuanyao whould answer anyway?